# How to suppress newpage when using titling

Tags: page-breaking, titles

I am using `titling` so I can reuse `\maketitle` many times in a document.  My document will be a sequence of around 100 abstracts for a conference, each with their own title and author.  I want to have two per page.

Try as I might, I cannot get more than one abstract per page.  `\maketitle` insists on starting a new page.  I want to turn that off.

I am on Mac OSX 10.8.2, using Texshop and `\documentclass[titlepage=false]{article}`.

Comment: Try `\inlinemaketitle` where `\newcommand{\inlinemaketitle}{{\let\newpage\relax\maketitle}}`. Could you provide a short [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your current problems?

Comment: Thank you!  That worked perfectly.  I simply replaced \maketitle with your \inlinemaketitle

Answer (score 3):

You can temporarily make `\newpage` a no-op by using `\inlinemaketitle` instead of the regular `\maketitle`, where

```
\newcommand{\inlinemaketitle}{{\let\newpage\relax\maketitle}}
```

The surrounding `{`...`}` limits the scope of the redefinition of `\newpage` to `\relax`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the proposed `\inlinemaketitle`, one could also `\renewcommand` the existing one. I have also added negative vspace to be able to fit more titles on the same page (it's just to help with deciding on a title):

```
\usepackage{titling}
\let\oldmaketitle\maketitle
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{{\let\newpage\relax\oldmaketitle\vspace{-7em}}}
```